# Can Reporting Services 2008 be used with SQL Server 2005 as the catalog database?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can you set up a Reporting Services 2008 reports server to use SQL Server 2005 for the report catalog database?

Comment: Good question! My thinking is probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes you can](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms156016.aspx). Quote:

> You can use an instance of the
>   Database Engine from SQL Server 2005
>   or SQL Server 2008 to host the
>   databases.

In the olden days, you could not host SSRS 2005 databases onto SQL Server 2000.